# Unable to access a parent variables from child class

Tags: php, oop

I want to reuse a few values from the parent class in the child class, but it seems that the child class cannot read the values that use the context `$this` in the parent method.

```
class Mother{

   public function __construct($field,$val){

       $this->field = $field;

       $this->val = $val;

   }

   public function set(){

        return array('val'=>$this->val,
                    'field'=>$this->field,
                    'test'=>"test");
   }

}

class Sister extends Mother{

   public function getVal(){

     $val = parent::set();

     print_r($val);

   }
}
```

The output would be

```
  Array ( [val] => [field] => [test] => test)
```

I have tried to turn the `set()` method static but that don't have anything to do with the problem. Can anyone tell me how to store the values in the parent class and pass it to the child class?

Comment: Please provide an example of how this code is used. We see the *declaration*, but not the *execution*.

Comment: You are assigning the values in parent class constructor. But child class does not have constructor method. We should call parent constructor from child class constructor like you call set method of parent class.

Comment: @ManikandanS The constructor of the parent is executed for the child as well!

Comment: @deceze oops.. sorry. Thanks for notify me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example will not print anything, because you don't call the class.

Try this

```
class Mother{

   public function __construct($field,$val){

       $this->field = $field;

       $this->val = $val;

   }

   public function set(){

        return array('val'=>$this->val,
                    'field'=>$this->field,
                    'test'=>"test");
   }

}

class Sister extends Mother{

   public function getVal(){

     $val = parent::set();

     return $val;

   }
}

$class = new Sister('test1', 'test2');

print_r($class->getVal());
```